# What is ARM Translation tools?

Tags: emulators, arm-processors

I came across [ARM Translation tools (1.1)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ARM%20Translation%201.1) for Android. What is the purpose of this library and how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library is part of Intel's Houdini project where ARM native code runs on Intel x86 using an emulation feature named Houdini (see [`libhoudini` Archives](https://lists.01.org/pipermail/android-ia/2012-September/thread.html)). This library basically maps ARM to x86 CPU instructions and its source code is closed (it was pulled from a working Lenovo laptop)<sup>[source](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/issues/283#issuecomment-312703449)</sup>. It reads ARM instructions on the fly and converts them to equivalent x86 instructions<sup>[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13005569/55075)</sup>.

[image: ARM Translation tools - Intel's Houdini project]

Related: [Will intel's houdini binary translator possibly help with emulation](https://www.reddit.com/r/emulation/comments/64bx4h/will_intels_houdini_binary_translator_possibly/) at reddit.

Comment: Just one quick question: How do you achieve this in an emulator environment? I know Remix Os emulator has a arm native bridge, I have posted this on Stackoverflow and no answers yet -  [How to enable arm native bridge in android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552313/how-to-enable-arm-native-bridge-in-android-emulator)